# ASP.Net MVC 4 Use of Attribute or BaseController?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, attributes

I have a controller with several actions. The Action should be redirected if the **IsCat** field on a service is false:

so something like this:

```
    public ActionResult MyCatAction()
    {
        if (MyService.IsCat==false)
            return RedirectToAnotherControllerAction();
     ...
```

Can this be done in an **Attribute** and applied to the entire Controller's set of Actions?

Comment: Puzzling number of upvotes... probably I'm missing something as answer is one search away - top answer on "mvc controller actionfilter" query...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Action filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410209%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) is the way to go in this case:

> Action filter, which wraps the action method execution. This filter
>   can perform additional processing, such as providing extra data to the
>   action method, inspecting the return value, or canceling execution of
>   the action method.

Here's a nice MSDN How To: [How to: Create a Custom Action Filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410056%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

In your case, you'd have something like this:

```
public class RedirectFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (MyService.IsCat==false)
            return RedirectToAnotherControllerAction();
    }
}
```

Then, you'd apply this filter on the controller level (apply to all controller actions)

```
[RedirectFilterAttribute]
public class MyController : Controller
{
   // Will apply the filter to all actions inside this controller.

    public ActionResult MyCatAction()
    {

    }    
}
```

or per action:

```
[RedirectFilterAttribute]
public ActionResult MyCatAction()
{
     // Action logic
     ...
}
```

Comment: +1. Consider adding global one too to complete the list: `GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new RedirectFilterAttribute());` to be called somewhere at startup.

Comment: @LenielMacaferi  is there a way that we apply to whole class leaving one or two actions ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

[Understanding Action Filters](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs)

> An action filter is an attribute. You can apply most action filters to either an individual controller action or an entire controller

(And you also can make it global to whole application).

Answer (score 1):

It should be failrly straightforward to do, and the MS docs have a very nice walkthrough:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381609(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can use an action filter and modify the result. Here's a simple attribute that will do something like that:

```
public class RedirectOnCat : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        if(MyService.IsCat == false)
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(/* whatever you need here */);
    }
}
```

You could also override `OnActionExecuted` on the controller in a very similar manner.